# Problems with running node module

Tags: node.js

So, I am getting the infamous error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/bc/projects/nodejs/pg-connect.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

here is the 2 line source causing it:

```
var pg = require('pg');
console.log("Hello world!");
```

Before asking for help here I have tried several things all of which didn't work:

1)I tried setting it to the absolute path, in my case:

```
var pg = require(/home/bc/node_modules/pg);
```

2)I tried copy/paste the above directory into my project directory.

3) I tried to install the module locally using:

```
npm install pg
```

However instead of the current directy it installed in the path `/hone/bc/node_modules`

I have no idea what more I can try to get it to work.

Comment: Did you attempt to install the module from your home directory?  `nom install NAME` will install the NAMEd module in the `node_modules` directory in the current directory (creating the node_modules dir as needed).

Comment: yes I did try to install it from my home directory.

Comment: The first time that is. Every next time I installed it from the correct folder.

Comment: Once the module has been installed, re-installing it will place it in the original installation directory. If you wish to move the install from one directory to another, you'll need to `npm remove NAME` first, which will remove the existing copy from its current location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, it appears that you've successfully installed the module, but in the wrong place.

A quick fix would be to copy the contents of `HOMEDIR/node_modules` into `CURRENTDIR/node_modules`.

Then you should be able to

```
var pg=require('pg');
```

To find "require-able" modules, Node will check the current directory for its module directory, unsuprisingly named "node_modules", and if it cannot find the module there, Node will move back up the directory path until it either finds a node_modules directory containing the required module or it hits the root. So, assuming your current directory is `/home/bc/projects/nodejs`, Node will look for the `pg` module in the following directories (in order):

```
/home/bc/projects/nodejs/node_modules/pg
/home/bc/projects/node_modules/pg
/home/bc/node_modules/pg
/home/node_modules/pg
/node_modules/pg
```

Comment: I accepted this as an answer, although for the record that was not the problem. As I have stated in my question, I have already tried that. I guess there was something wrong with the file since when I tried to open it with vi it just said "new file". I created a new file and copy/pasted the content (I still had the old file open in atom) and it worked.

Comment: So, you installed the module and then edited the file at `/home/bc/projects/nodejs/pg-connect.js` and it worked? That is very strange. Are you sure you used `require("pg")`?

Comment: Hmm... `pg-connect.js` does not appear to be part of the `pg` module. Is this a file you created?

Comment: Yes that is the file I created. I think that atom just didn't properly create the file or something.

Comment: Err, ok. But this means your question was never about the `pg` module at all. ;-)

Comment: Apparently so, though your answer led me to the conclusion that it might not be from the installation rather the file.